# 3rd party file_get_contents behind proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, environment-variables, file-get-contents

I'm using a 3rd party library, which is using file_get_contents() to retrieve external documents. Because I'm behind a proxy, I got the error:

```
file_get_contents(http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

I tested file_get_contents() with a proxy setting via stream_context_create():

```
$context = stream_context_create([
  'http' => [
    'proxy' => 'tcp://SERVERNAME:PORT',
    'request_fulluri' => true
  ]
]);
```

and this works fine!!

The problem is I cannot configure the 3rd party library with my proxy settings. Is there a way to configure this proxy setting system wide, so that file_get_contents() can use this setting, like with curl?

```
export http_proxy=http://SERVERNAME:PORT
```

with curl from 3rd party libraries works fine. But file_get_contents() seems not to recognize environment variables.

```
export http_proxy=tcp://SERVERNAME:PORT
export tcp_proxy=tcp://SERVERNAME:PORT
```

both not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `stream_context_set_default` ? It can help settings context globally.